# Memorizing values upon an async call in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-usememo

I'm trying to memorize some values in a react component because it's re rendering even when data hasn't changed (and wont change). Using useEffect + useState the data displays correctly, but the functions are triggered each time the component is re rendered. Currently am trying to implement the useMemo hook but the async call/promise is not resolving in the render process, so it doesn't even loads the data. I'll try to give the most information out of this:

This is my AppRouter component, i create the contract and pass it as value to a provider that will be used in some other components:

```
import { useWeb3React } from "@web3-react/core";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import { AdminScreen } from "../components/admin/AdminScreen";
import { ContractsContext } from "../components/ContractsContext";
import { Navbar } from "../components/ui/Navbar";
import { getLibrary } from "../helpers/web3Getters";
import { useCreateContract, useGetLibrary } from "../hooks.js/contractsHooks";
import { createContract } from "../web3-utils/contractCreation";
import { MarketRoutes } from "./MarketRoutes";
import { PrivateRoute } from "./PrivateRoute";

export const AppRouter = () => {
  const context = useWeb3React();
  //console.log("[1] context in app router: ", context);

  const { contract: kolorTokenContract, loading: loadingContract } =
    useCreateContract(
      context,
      "0x9414f981a5B5ef2bE455f2427E2166c35e8989fB",
      "abis/KolorToken.json"
    );

  return (
    //<p>{loadingLibrary ? "library ready" : "loading library"}</p>

    <ContractsContext.Provider value={[kolorTokenContract]}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        {/* Set private route for Admining nfts & tokens */}
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/admin"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <AdminScreen />
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />

          <Route path="/*" element={<MarketRoutes />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ContractsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The contract is then obtained from my custom context in the admin route (which is what im testing now) and then passed to one of its children:

```
import React, { memo, useContext, useMemo } from "react";
import { getERC20Info } from "../../helpers/tokenGetters";
import { useGetERC20Info } from "../../hooks.js/contractsHooks";
import { ContractsContext } from "../ContractsContext";

export const TokenInfo = memo((tokenContract) => {
  //const { _address: ERC20Address } = tokenContract;
  const { address, owner, vault, supply } = useGetERC20Info(tokenContract);

  //const result = useMemo(() => getERC20Info(tokenContract), [tokenContract]);

  //console.log("contract from tokeninfo:", tokenContract);
  //console.log("result: ", result);

  return (
    <div className="row align-items-center">
      <div className="col-8 col-md-6 col-sm-4 ">Minting Form</div>
      <div className="col-4 col-md-3 col-sm-2 animate__animated animate__fadeInRightBig">
        <h2>Kolor Token Info</h2>
        <p>
          Address: <b>{address}</b>
        </p>
        <p>
          Owner: <b>{owner}</b>
        </p>
        <p>
          Vault: <b>{vault}</b>
        </p>
        <p>
          Current supply: <b>{supply}</b>
        </p>
      </div>

      <hr />
    </div>
  );
});
```

Actually i'm using a custom hook with useState and useEffect to fetch the data, but it re renders the TokenInfo component even when the tokenContract hasn't changed at all. This is my custom hook:

```
export const useGetERC20Info = (contract) => {
  //console.log("contract from usegeterc20info effect: ", contract);

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    address: "loading...",
    owner: "loading...",
    vault: "loading...",
    supply: "loading",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getERC20Info(contract).then(({ address, owner, vault, supply }) => {
      setState({
        address,
        owner,
        vault,
        supply,
      });
      return () => {
        setState({});
      };
    });
  }, [contract]);

  return state;
};
```

My getERC20Info function, tries to fetch data from the blockchain, nothing wrong with that, its working fine:

```
export const getERC20Info = async (contract) => {
  console.log("getting erc20 info...");
  console.log("contract from geterc20info: ", contract);

  const { _address: address } = contract;
  const owner = await getERC20Owner(contract);
  const vault = await getERC20Vault(contract);
  const supply = await getERC20Supply(contract);

  //console.log("supply: ", supply);

  return {
    address,
    owner,
    vault,
    supply,
  };
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It might be better design to raise the fetching up a level, i.e., pass the ERC20Info into the component.

Comment: I have a hunch that your problem stems from some component higher up the tree gets re-rendered, which would trigger a re-render on all component further down. Keep in mind that this is just speculation, but it might help steer your focus.

Comment: @HenrikKlev but if i fetch the data one level up, wouldnt be the same?

Comment: @HenrikKlev i was thinking the same, whenever i change route and come back to the parent route that renders the token info it fetches the data again with useEffect. Also wrapping the whole component with React.memo doesn't work

Comment: Sorry for not responding for a while. I'm looking into a solution as we speak. I'll update once I've done some investigating.

Comment: Where is the TokenInfo rendered from? I still cannot see anything that sticks out. If I understand correctly, then the prop tokenContract is passed through the ContractsContext? How does that context look like?